# To find which button is clicked in javascript php

Tags: php, javascript

How to findout which button is clicked.

```
`<input type="submit" name="quest" id="ques" value="quest" />
<input type="submit" name="answer" id="ans" value="answer"  />`
```

Comment: it is not twitter you can go over 160 characters..

Answer (score 1):

Its easy you can code like i did

Code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script language="javascript">         
         function checkBtn(event) {
               alert(event.target.name);
         }
      </script>


   </head>
   <body>
      <br /><br />
      <form action="multiSubmit.php" method="post" onSubmit="return false;">
         <input type="submit" name="quest" id="quest" value="quest" onClick="checkBtn(event)" /><br />
         <input type="submit" name="answer" id="answer" value="answer" onClick="checkBtn(event)" /><br />
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should look like below

```
<script language="javascript">         
   function checkBtn(event) {
         alert(event.target.name);
     }
</script>
```

Add a `onClick="checkBtn(event)"` to your every Button. Else you can add a `onsubmit` to your form like this `onSubmit="checkBtn(event)"`

Comment: But by clicking the question and answer button, I have two seperate forms. So, I've to write seperate conditions for both buttons within one validate function.Is it possible to write. Please tell me.

Comment: within the checkBtn function you can write whatever you want and submit the correct form as you want

Comment: read this for form submit. http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml